# Does mysqlcheck checks for foreign keys constrain

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I was reading the documentation of `mysqlcheck` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlcheck.html#option_mysqlcheck_check), but i can't undestand what does `--check`, i mean, I can't understand what error does it checks (I can only find `Check the tables for errors. This is the default operation.`).

(My goal is to check for foreign key constrain since I've inserteda bunch of records using `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this test:

```
DROP TABLE test2;
DROP TABLE test1;

CREATE TABLE test1(id INT primary key)  ENGINE INNODB;
CREATE TABLE test2(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CONSTRAINT fk_test1 FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES test1 (id)
) ENGINE INNODB;

INSERT INTO test1 VALUES (1);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;

INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (3);

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
SELECT @@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;

-- INSERT INTO test2 VALUES (4);

SELECT * FROM test1;
SELECT * FROM test2;
```

Outputs:

```
0
```

```
1
```

```
id
1
```

```
id
1
2
3
```

Then I've run `mysqlcheck`:

```
>mysqlcheck -c -u root testdb test2
testdb.test2                                     OK
```

So I think this `Check the tables for errors.` means errors in data storage (low level), not data consistency

Running `CHECK TABLE test2` expectedly gives the same result.

I couldn't find an easy way to chekc foreign keys after turning this check on. It seems the only thing to do is to use with `information_schema` writing selects for all FK constraints.